# Can I list all dependent objects of an object (say, user)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model and can manually check every (`:has_many`, `:has_one`) dependency, but I want some magic like `current_user.attributes` for records. So when I update model, I don't need to update method.

I tried [Reflections](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html), but it returns all theoretical dependencies/connections of model, isn't it? And I need dependent records from DB.

Something like `X.where(user_id: @user.id)` or `@user.dependents`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign required object to `model` and then

```
model.class.reflect_on_all_associations.map { |table| model.method(table.name).call }.select(&:any?)
```

For example:

```
user = User.first
user.class.reflect_on_all_associations.map { |table| user.method(table.name).call }.select(&:any?)
# returns all associated objects of first user
```

You can specify result using `:has_many`, `:has_one` or `:belongs_to` as argument of `reflect_on_all_associations`.

Possibly there is more elegant way, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR Don't do this :)

You can do something quite similar using reflections. For example

```
@user.class.reflections.keys.flat_map { |reflection| me.send(reflection) }
```

will give you an array with all the objects associated with the user. But what's next?

For almost *any* real-world logic around this list's members (except the basics that come from AR::Base) you will have to check either a class of an object or use bug-prone `try` magic - both options are reasonable trade-off sometimes, but in most practical cases I'd prefer less smelly solutions (even if they are a bit more verbose).

Comment: Thank you for answer. I accepted another one, because I got it working straight away. But I agree with you that it's a mess — I started thinking about it right after finding that I can't do it, but couldn't help but asking just to be sure it's possible)